# Surprising properties of closed planar curves

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, curves-and-surfaces, curves

In https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.05422 I proved with elementary topological methods that a smooth planar curve with total turning number a non-zero integer multiple of $2\pi$ (the tangent fully turns a non-zero number of times) can always be split into 3 arcs rearrangeable to a closed smooth curve. Here comes one example of what I called the 2-cut theorem.

[image: Example]

I am now writing the introduction to my thesis and I would like to cite more examples of counterintuitive properties of planar closed curves like, I think, the one above. The inscribed square problem, asking whether every Jordan curve admits an inscribed square (pic from [Jordan curves admitting only acyclic inscriptions of squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275439/jordan-curves-admitting-only-acyclic-inscriptions-of-squares)), alredy came to my mind.

[image]

Such a property is still a conjecture for the general case, but proofs have been provided for several special cases and the easier inscribed rectangle problem can be solved with a beautiful topological argument (3Blue1Brown made a very nice video about that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmgkSdhK4K8&t=169s).

My question: **what are other surprising/counterintuitive properties of closed planar curves you are aware of?**

Note: this question was originally posted on MathStackExchange since I thought it was suitable for a more general audience. Apparently, it requires a slightly broader knowledge of literature.

Comment: Post at m.se is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723039/surprising-properties-of-closed-planar-curves

Comment: See this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/269261/53155

Comment: I'd like to post links to some MO questions related to Jordan curves (I wish I've done this right away). Perhaps this will attract additional attention to them. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357508/chord-of-fixed-length-traveling-around-a-jordan-curve and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296585/enveloping-a-jordan-curve-with-a-trace-of-another-one?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: maybe this also qualifies: "Can a Jordan arc be included into a Jordan loop?"
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75213/including-a-jordan-arc-into-a-jordan-loop-can-the-magi-go-home-by-another-way

Answer (score 7):

The Four Vertex Theorem, due to Mukhopadhyaya in 1909, states that a plane closed simple smooth curve with positive curvature has at least four vertices, where a vertex is a local maximum or minimum of the curvature. There's a detailed discussion in a chapter of Fuchs and Tabachnikov, Mathematical Omnibus.

Comment: The assumption of positive total curvature is not enough, you need a simple curve. For some Pascal's Limaçons admit only two vertices.

Answer (score 6):

**Chakerian's Theorem** (proved in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103036705)) that a closed curve of length  L in the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has [total curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_curvature) at least L.

(In [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2034901?seq=1) later paper Chakerian gave a simpler proof and noted that equality holds iff the curve is of length $2\pi n$ and winds round the unit circle $n$ times.)

Comment: This is fun! Does there exist something similar of a sphere of surface $S$ instead of a curve?

Answer (score 6):

One result that I initially found a bit surprising is Grayson's theorem. It's a little bit of a different flavor than the other examples but I think it's interesting and worth a mention.

Given a closed planar curve $\gamma$ which is smooth enough ($C^2$ is sufficient but it's possible to be deal with less regular curves), there is a process known as curve shortening flow, which deforms the curve using the flow
$$ \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t} = \kappa N. $$

Here, $\kappa$ is the unsigned curvature and $N$ is the unit normal vector. This is called curve shortening flow because it tends to shrink curves.

Grayson's theorem states that if you start with a closed curve that does not cross itself, then under the flow it will remain embedded and eventually become convex. Gage and Hamilton had earlier shown that a convex curve shrinks to a round point, so this shows that any embedded curve shrinks to a round point.

Grayson's original proof is pretty involved. Now there are more conceptual proofs of this result (Huisken has a particularly nice one), so it's a bit less surprising. Nonetheless, it's possible to draw some really [crazy curves](https://youtu.be/wHfpacPLHIA) and somehow the flow avoids itself and makes the curve convex. A good resource for this is Anthony Carapetis' website, which has an [applet](http://a.carapetis.com/csf/) demonstrating the flow. Note that if you allow the curve to cross itself, the theorem fails and you can get local kinks to appear.

Comment: Thank you! I awarded the bounty for the concise and clear presentation, and for the link to the interactive resource.

Answer (score 3):

I post as an answer to not overload the original entry and to contribute myself to the nice flow of results.

Browsing the book "Unsolved problems in geometry: Unsolved Problems in Intuitive Mathematics" by Croft, Falconer and Guy (after a good hint from the Reddit user Giovanni_Resta), the following properties of closed convex planar curves came out.

- **Given any closed convex planar curve, there always exist three concurrent chords bisecting each other and cutting at prescribed angle.** The reference given is "On chords of convex curves", H. Steinhaus - Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Cl. III, 1957, which I was not able to find online. The general problem for simple closed curve is apparently still open and very much related to the general inscribed square problem I already mentioned in the question.
- **Given any closed convex planar curve, there exists a point in its interior which lies on 4 normals through 4 distinct boundary points.** The theorem was proven by Heil also for 3D convex bodies and 6 normals and it is conjectured for convex bodies of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $2d$ normals. The reference given is "Concurrent normals and critical points under weak smoothness assumptions", E. Heil - NYASA, 1985.

To those, I add a characterization for $C^3$ closed planar curves (not necessarily simple), which I found in "Robust fairing via conformal curvature" - K. Crane, U. Pinkall, and P. Schröder, ACM Trans. Graphics 32, 2013.

**A $C^3$ planar curve $\gamma$ parametrized on $[a,b]$ and with curvature $k$ is closed iff $\int_a^b k'\gamma=0 $.**

If it is not surprising, it is at least a weird relation between dependent descriptors.

Answer (score 3):

How about the ``Oval's Problem" of [Benguria and Loss](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0402048).  This is a (somewhat surprisingly) open problem connecting spectral theory with plane geometry.  The conjecture is that for any simple closed curve $\sigma$ of length $2\pi$ and any periodic function $f:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}$ one has
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} |f'(s)|^2+\kappa(s)^2 |f(s)|^2 ds \geq \gamma \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(s)|^2 ds
$$
for $\gamma=1$.  Here $s$ is the arclength parameter and $\kappa(s)$ is the geodesic curvature. In other words, the lowest eigenvalue of $-\frac{d^2}{ds^2}+\kappa(s)^2$ is bounded from below by $1$ on a closed curve.  This lowest bound is achieved by the circle, but is actually achieved by a whole family of "ovals" that deteriorate to a multiplicity two line segment.  Interestingly, this problem is related the sharp Lieb-Thirring inequality which is a purely spectral theoretic problem (this was Benguria and Loss's motivation).  It is also related to minimal surface theory.

In their paper, Benguria and Loss show that this inequality holds with $\gamma=\frac{1}{2}$.  This is actually, sharp if one expands the set of curves to include those that total turning number 1 so one has to use the curve is closed in some way (and not just that $\int_0^{2\pi} k(s)ds=2\pi$.  Various other authors have worked on parts of this problem: [Burchard and Thomas](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02922244) showed the ovals where local minima of the lowest eigenvalue (so the problem is solved near curves in the family, [Linde](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-12/S0002-9939-06-08483-8/) showed closed convex curves have $\gamma\geq 0.6085$, [Denzler](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6322.pdf) showed there is a closed convex curve that minimized the value of $\gamma$ and [Bernstein and Mettler](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.8000) discussed the symmetry of the problem (related to projective geometry) and showed some weaker geometric inequalities held for closed convex curves (but not for curves of turning number 1).